# How to get project name/id from Google Cloud Storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm given a Google Cloud Storage bucket address (`gs://some_bucket_name`) to which I've already been granted read access.  The bucket belongs to another project.  Is there any way for me to find out what the project name or id that the bucket belongs to?

Comment: what type of access do you have (service account, IAM, public read)?

Answer (score 9):

You can get the bucket **project number** using the Storage JSON API. More specifically, you can request `GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/<BUCKET_NAME>`. For more details and to test this request, check this document: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/get

Once you get the project number you can get the project_id and / or name using either `gcloud` or the [resource manager API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list)

Here is a complete example to get the project_id and name of a bucket:

```sh
authorization flow
# the user <ACCOUNT> must have these permission 
# storage.buckets.get
# resourcemanager.projects.get on the bucket project 
gcloud auth login <ACCOUNT>

BUCKET_NAME=<BUCKET_NAME>

ACCESS_TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-access-token)

PROJECT_NUMBER=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/${BUCKET_NAME} | jq -r .projectNumber)

gcloud projects list --filter="PROJECT_NUMBER=${PROJECT_NUMBER}" --format="value(PROJECT_ID, NAME)"
```

Comment: This answer only works for the legacy API, not for buckets with uniform object access, which is now default.

Answer (score 9):

I did this today with a combination of two commands run from gcloud in your terminal or from [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell)

1. `gcloud storage buckets describe gs://<your-bucket> | grep projectNumber` - this returns the project number
2. `gcloud projects describe <projectNumber>` - this returns information about the project that includes both the project name and ID.

Comment: Keep in mind that this will only work if you have a permission to see ACLs for that bucket. Usually requires a high level role for the bucket, e.g. `Storage Object Creator` or `Storage Object Admin` or `Storage Admin`.

Answer (score 5):

A good question.

Buckets don't have obvious scoping to projects and their globally unique names aren't presented as part of hierarchy that includes project identifiers.

However... acls may be a good bet... I'm not **certain** that this definitive, please check:

```
gsutil acl get gs://[[BUCKET-NAME]]
```

Which yields the `projectNumber`:

```
[
  {
    "entity": "project-owners-123456789012",
    "projectTeam": {
      "projectNumber": "123456789012",
      "team": "owners"
    },
    "role": "OWNER"
  },
  {
    "entity": "project-editors-123456789012",
    "projectTeam": {
      "projectNumber": "123456789012",
      "team": "editors"
    },
    "role": "OWNER"
  },
  {
    "entity": "project-viewers-123456789012",
    "projectTeam": {
      "projectNumber": "123456789012",
      "team": "viewers"
    },
    "role": "READER"
  }
]
```

Comment: `gsutil ls -L -b gs://[[BUCKET-NAME]]` and you can use APIs Explorer too: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/storage.buckets.get/m/storage/v1/storage.buckets.get?bucket=[[BUCKET-NAME]]`

Comment: This is a good answer provided that the primitive `READER` has been granted. However, the IAM roles `role/viewer`, `roles/storage.legacyObjectReader` and `roles/storage.objectViewer` do not grant access to ACLs. The answer depends on the exact permissions that are granted to the user.

Comment: This answer only works for the legacy API, not for buckets with uniform object access, which is now default.

Answer (score 3):

**[gcloud asset search-all-resources](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/asset/search-all-resources)** works best for me.

Important to define [scope](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/asset/search-all-resources#--scope), otherwise it searches only the active project.

`gcloud asset search-all-resources --scope folders/<number> --asset-types=storage.googleapis.com/bucket --filter='name:some_bucket_name'`